# xsl 2.0 - how to change duration notification `PT11H22M` to 11.22

Tags: xslt-2.0

really I canot find it how to change this duration notification

`PT11H22M` to 11.22

but it seems like easy comand

Comment: I have no idea why this question should be downvoted. Upvoting simply to compensate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have the value "PT11H22M" as a string:

```
<xsl:variable name="s" as="xs:string" select="'PT11H22M'"/>
```

Assuming your duration is always less than 24 hours, you can convert the string "PT11H22M" to a duration using

```
<xsl:variable name="d" as="xs"dayTimeDuration" 
              select="xs:dayTimeDuration($s)"/>
```

You can then convert this to a time-of-day using

```
<xsl:variable name="t" as="xs:time" select="xs:time('00:00:00') + $d"/>
```

And you can then format this as the string "11.22" using

```
<xsl:variable name="out" as="xs:string" 
              select="format-time($t, '[H01].[m01]')"/>
```

Alternatively you can extract the hours and minutes components of a duration using `fn:hours-from-duration` and `fn:minutes-from-duration`, and then format these as numbers using `fn:format-number`.